# How to implement internal DNS caching within simple Java web proxy?

Tags: java, caching, proxy, dns

My goal is to implement internal DNS caching within the proxy: basically to save my DNS resolutions for future use and before you need one, check if you have the required resolution in the cache. For simplicity I'm ignoring TTL and instead using the default of up to 30 seconds. How would I go about doing something like this, even pointer to the right direction would be much appreciated? My Java web proxy looks very similar to the one in the example here http://www.jtmelton.com/2007/11/27/a-simple-multi-threaded-java-http-proxy-server/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two classes I wrote to solve this problem

#### DnsCache

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

/**
 * Singleton class that holds the ExpiringMap used for DNS Cache
 */
public class DnsCache {
    private static ExpiringMap<String, InetAddress> theDnsCache = null;

    public static ExpiringMap<String, InetAddress> getInstance() {
        if (theDnsCache == null) {
            theDnsCache = new ExpiringMap<String, InetAddress>();
        }
        return theDnsCache;
    }
}
```

#### ExpiringMap

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * A HashMap that removes objects after the set TTL
 */
public class ExpiringMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
    private final int DEFAULT_TTL = 30;
    private final HashMap<K, ScheduledFuture<K>> cacheKeys = new HashMap<K, ScheduledFuture<K>>();
    private final HashMap<K, V> theHash = new HashMap<K, V>();
    private ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return theHash.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return theHash.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return theHash.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return theHash.containsValue(value);
    }

    /**
     * If retrieving an object that already exists in the cache 
     * we must resets the TTL timer on that item.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public V get(final Object key) {
        // If item exists in cache, then we cancel and reset the timer on that item
        if(cacheKeys.containsKey(key) && cacheKeys.get(key).cancel(false)) {
            ScheduledFuture<K> task = executorService.schedule(new Callable<K>() {
                @Override
                public K call() {
                    cacheKeys.remove(key);
                    theHash.remove(key);
                    return (K) key;
                }
            }, DEFAULT_TTL, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            cacheKeys.put((K) key, task);
        }
        return theHash.get(key);
    }

    /**
     * When we add an item to cache we add the key to a map that contains FutureScheduled 
     * events that will remove the item after TTL
     */
    @Override
    public V put(final K key, V value) {
        ScheduledFuture<K> task = executorService.schedule(new Callable<K>() {
            @Override
            public K call() {
                cacheKeys.remove(key);
                theHash.remove(key);
                return key;
            }
        }, DEFAULT_TTL, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        cacheKeys.put(key, task);
        return theHash.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        cacheKeys.remove(key);
        return theHash.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        // TODO implement

    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        cacheKeys.clear();
        theHash.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return theHash.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return theHash.values();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return theHash.entrySet();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that Java already has a mechanism to cache DNS requests ?

Have a look at:

```
networkaddress.cache.ttl
networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl
```

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html)